# Objective-c get data from webview request before it loads page

Tags: ios, objective-c, webview, uiwebview

Im looking for solution to get data from UIwebview request before it loads, or any other way to just fetch content, and do not run javascript after it finis to load. I need to get response, and stop loading webview. I can't use nsurl request.Thank you

Comment: Why can't you use an `NSURLRequest`?  That seems like it would be the obvious solution here.

Comment: this request must be executed in webview, it needs to be authenticated by user, there are a lot values hard to reproduce. I just need fetch response from successful request before javascript on the response will execute.Even if i could not get data before it loads in webview, i think there must be tricky way to solve this, but i didn't come up with any successful idea yet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I remember, you can't get a response from UIWebView. The only option is to block loading of a particular request using `-webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:` and download it manually (I know, that you don't want to do it, but I'm afraid, it's the only option that I know of).

As for the request authentication, you could ask the user if he/she wants to perform the request in `-webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:`.

Comment: NSURLRequest from shouldStartLoadWithRequest is fully configured with user agent,cookies and all header values?

Comment: @Daniel, unfortunately, I don't remember. I had a similar task, but it was about two years ago.

Comment: @Daniel, note, that starting from iOS 7 the recommended way of performing requests manually is to use `NSURLSession` instead of `NSURLRequest`.

Comment: @FreeNickname What's working? Daniel's comment or the answer?